# How to hook into beforeSuite event with Codeception for API Acceptance tests?

Tags: api, codeception, acceptance

I am building API Acceptance tests with Codeception.

I am familiar with Unit tests there and I used the setUp method in those classes for all logic required before running all the tests of the class.

However I didn't find anything like this for Acceptance Tests.

Notice that I am using the "Class" approach, not the procedural way.

So I have a class like this...

```
class ResourceCest {
    public function _beforeSuite(ApiTester $I)
    {
        // Ideally this would work, but it doesn't.
    }

    public function _before(ApiTester $I) 
    {
        $I->am('Api Tester');
    }
    public function somethingThatIWantToExecute(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $I->sendGet('something');
        // etc
    }
}
```

I can make a method like setUp, but then Codeception executes it as a test and thus outputting something when running the tests.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't define the `_beforeSuite` inside your `Cest` classes. Instead, you should use the Helper class inside `_support`.

Assuming you have a suite called `api`, you should have a `ApiHelper.php` class inside `_support`. There, you can define your methods, for instance:

```php
<?php
namespace Codeception\Module;

// here you can define custom actions
// all public methods declared in helper class will be available in $I

class ApiHelper extends \Codeception\Module
{
    public function _beforeSuite($I) {
        var_dump($I);
        die();
    }
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Does not work for me. Instead of `$I` defined as a `AcceptanceTester` I got an configuration array inside of `_beforeSuite` method

Comment: $settings array is passed into _beforeSuite. if you want $I then you do this $I = $this;.